# react-native-permission message is not same as written in info.plist file in ios

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-webview, react-native-permissions

I've created an ios webview app where the chatbot loads in and asks user for the microphone permission.
using react-native-permission npm I've changed the pod files and info.plist files as mentioned in documentation.
But I'm not getting the same message as I've mentioned in info.plist file. I can able to allow and deny the permissions but the message is not same as in info.plist file
[image: permission message in info.plist file]

[image: permission message while running]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Probably because the web view is requesting the permission, not your app.  There is a difference between giving an app microphone permission and a web site

Comment: Thank you Paulw11 
How to change the permission message from the app rather than the webview

Comment: Don't use a web view; Have your app access the microphone. If you are going to use a web view you are stuck with its permission dialog.

Comment: @Paulw11 yes the app have the access for the microphone. 
what needs to be used to render a chatbot UI onto the react-native.  
I cannot use the in-app browser as it contains the UI elements of the browser

Comment: Then you can't change the permission message.

Comment: @Paulw11 Thank you 
Is there any way this permission can be stored in persistent storage once the microphone permission is allowed?